# Limit Chrome Extension Permissions to Certain Domain

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension that I have running only on a certain domain using "matches":[] in my manifest.json. However, because I need the "webNavigation" permission to run the listener script below, users are told that my extension is able to read their browsing history upon installing. I don't think this is the case, because of the aforementioned "matches."

Below is the listener script I use to run my extension's code when they get on a certain page.

```html
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"content.js"});
});
```

Is there a way to do this without telling the user that the extension is listening to all browsing history?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(details) {
    chrome.tabs.executeScript(null,{file:"content.js"});
} ,{
url: {
    hostContains: 'foo.com'
  }
});
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work at all, Chrome still asks for "read your browsing history" permission.